# Python multiple separate pivot tables based on another column to separate excel files

Tags: python, loops, pivot, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to produce multiple separate pivot tables for each distinct value in a different column in my df (like a different pivot table filtered by each). In the actual file there are several hundred R1's so was trying to find a way to loop over this somehow to produce them separately.

If possible is there a way to then send each pivot to a separate excel file

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Employee':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20'],
'R1': ['mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'stacey' , 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey'],
'R2':['bill', 'bill', 'bill', 'bill', 'bill', 'chris', 'chris', 'chris', 'jill',  'jill', 'jill', 'tom', 'tom', 'tom', 'tom', 'pete', 'pete', 'pete', 'pete', 'pete']})
df
```

So essentially 1 excel file for mike's world that has a count by employee by R2 and 1 excel for stacey's world that has a count by employee of R2 (but in the real data this would be done for the several hundred R1's)

thanks!

Mike excel
[image]

Stacey excel
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there may be prettier ways in dealing with the dataframes prior to writing to the sheets, this provided me the results you were looking for. It should scale with any number of 'R1''s as "unique()" provides a list of the unique names within R1. Then breaks it down for the variables you need and writes it to a sheet on the given filepath.

```
import pandas as pd
data_jobs2=pd.DataFrame({'Employee':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20'],
'L2Name': ['mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'stacey' , 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey', 'stacey'],
'L3Name':['bill', 'bill', 'bill', 'bill', 'bill', 'chris', 'chris', 'chris', 'jill',  'jill', 'jill', 'tom', 'tom', 'tom', 'tom', 'pete', 'pete', 'pete', 'pete', 'pete']})
values = data_jobs2['L2Name'].unique()
filepath = 'Your\File\Path\Here\File_name.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='openpyxl')
for i in values:
    series = data_jobs2[data_jobs2['L2Name'] == i].groupby(['L2Name','L3Name'])['Employee'].count().to_frame().reset_index()
    df_to_write = series.pivot(index = 'L2Name', columns='L3Name', values = 'Employee').reset_index().replace({i : 'Count of Employee'}).rename(columns={'L2Name':''}).set_index('')
    df_to_write['Grand Total'] = df_to_write.sum(1)
    df_to_write.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i)
    display(df_to_write)
    display(series)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I am getting an 'ValueError: Must pass explicit sheet_name or set cur_sheet property' in the filepath do i need to specify an excel sheet name perhaps?

Comment: This implies that you have a sheet name of None or null. Do you have anything in 'R1' that is null? If so I'd replace those with a descriptive string. For example df['R1'].fillna('No Name', inplace=True) would replace nulls with No Name and update a sheet with 'No Name' instead.

Comment: Thanks again so much for all your help!! I just needed to add a line for writer.close() and writer.save() at the end of your code and it worked!